# Symfony - not working rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, symfony-1.4

The rewrite is not working.

- `site/index.php/page` works;
- `site/page` - does not work;

I use symfony 1.4.

`.htaccess` standard:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
 # getting no_script_name to work
 #RewriteBase /

 # we skip all files with .something
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
 #RewriteRule .* - [L]

 # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
 RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please check these things: What is the output of `sudo a2enmod rewrite`? Do you have `AllowOverride All` in virtual host config (like it is in the [docs](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony#chapter_03_sub_the_secure_way))? Do you have `no_script_name: true` in the default app's (e.g. frontend) `settings.yml`?

Comment: @1ed: a2enmod rewrite gave me a "Enabling module rewrite". Then I restarted the server, and all went fine. Thanks !

Comment: @1ed: for the answer to be accepted, you will have to ask user1659698. Here is an upvote, though :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable `mod_rewrite` using `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, and then restart the server.